# Turning folder with python files into executable

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller, exe

I have a folder with 10 python files that all work together to run my main python file/program. (All of my python work is done through pycharm). Can I download the whole folder as an exe, or will I have to download all of the files as exe's separately and then find a way to run them all together?

Comment: You can create one exe file that runs all of them

Comment: `pyinstaller` (https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) is the tool you need. Just pass your main python file as an argument. Choose `--one-file` option to have a single and standalone executable file.